# Unnecessary rebuild in Visual Studio 2013: .RSP build input is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild, vcxproj

I have mixed C#/C++ solution in VS2013. One of the C++ projects is getting rebuilt every time I run build even when nothing is changed. In the diagnostic output it says:

```
1> Project not up to date because the following 1 build inputs were missing:
1>  up to date is missing: 'PROJECT_OUTPUT_PATH\TMP_RANDOMGUID.RSP'
```

When I run MSBuild.exe from cmd line, I get following output:

```
"…\TMP_RANDOMGUID.RSP" does not exist; source compilation required.
```

Note that random guid changes every time I run build.

This .rsp file is listed as input file for the task "LIB" among other .obj files.

A lot of projects are dependent on this one, so this triggers a rebuild of almost entire solution.

I found out on MSDN that .rsp is MSBuild response file which contains MSBuild.exe command line switches. It looks like the project is configured so that every compile is through a generated .rsp file, can this be turned off in Visual Studio?

Comment: You are not going to get an answer unless you document your problem better.  At least the detailed build trace, post it to a paste bin.

Comment: Can you post the rsp file ?

Comment: rsp file does not exist

Answer (score -2):

Perform this steps if as apply to your environment:

1. Delete every single output folder of your solution and projects (typically called "Debug", "Release", "x86" and "x64")
2. Delete every precompiled output folders of your solution and projects (typically called "ipch")
3. Delete files *.filters, *.user, *.sdf, *.suo
4. Invoke msbuild with clean target: msbuild /t:clean
5. Invoke msbuild: msbuild
6. It is done. Now you should be able to recompile only the based on file changes.